# Dom loads two times

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have a very weird problem. I am using jQuery and i am using the $(function () to load functions when the dom is loaded. But with a unknown reason the code in the $(function () will run a second time. A preview is at: http://development.devhouse.nl/news/3/het-nieuwste-nieuwsbericht you will get 2 alert prompts, but there is only 1 written in a $(function () . The exact code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            alert('Test');
        });
</script>
```

And the whole source can be found here(open the source in your browser): http://development.devhouse.nl/news/3/het-nieuwste-nieuwsbericht

Please help me. I am hopeless....

Tom

Comment: Strange: when setting a breakpoint on `alert('Test');`, the first alert pops up before the breakpoint is reached. On continuing the second one shows up. When setting a breakpoint on `$(function () {` Firefox stops *before* the first alert pops up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose because the script is in your html `body` instead of in the head. Move it to the `head`, and it only fires once.

Is there a reason you have it there?

**EDIT:** For clarification, as **Marcel Korpel** noted, scripts can be nested in the `body`, and there can be performance reasons to have them at the end. But in this situation, the script was nested inside an element within the `body`. This works, but can lead to unexpected behavior if that element is manipulated in certain ways.

Comment: Why is this? It shouldn't matter where a function resides, should it?

Comment: @Marcel - Yes, you're right. Probably was something else going on that was manipulating that element, like `appendTo()`, or something. In any  case, not the optimal place for your scripts.

Comment: @patrick: Hmm, first you say I am right, then you say "not the optimal place for your scripts." :P Well, it *is* when optimizing a page for speed: http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom

Comment: @Marcel - In terms of the script running, you were right that it can be in the `body`. But not optimal in its placement in the middle of the `body` as the child of an `h1` element (or something). Bottom of the page (as your link suggested) would make more sense. I didn't mean optimal in terms of performance. More in terms of practicality (as the issue demonstrated).

Comment: @patrick: Ah, it was in the middle of an `h1`, I didn't notice that (and it was gone when the OP changed his page). Nonetheless, it's considered best practice to put your scripts in a separate file.

Comment: @Marcel - Agreed. And I'll edit my answer with a clarification, as you brought up valid points.

Answer (score 1):

```
$().ready(function(){
     alert('Test');
});
```